# How to read variable from database

Tags: java, android, mysql, database, variables

In this android coding, I declared the variable path inline. 
I wanted to retrieve the variable from database, since the IPTV source changing every weeks

Here's is the code:

```
private String path = "rtmp://live.dltv.cn:1935/live/live11";

private VideoView mVideoView;
ProgressBar progressBar = null;
 public menu1(){}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu1_layout, container, false);
    mVideoView = (VideoView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.surface_view);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

    if (!io.vov.vitamio.LibsChecker.checkVitamioLibs(getActivity())){
        Log.d("TAG", "Could not load");
    }
    if (path.equals("")) {
        // Tell the user to provide a media file URL/path.
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please edit VideoViewDemo Activity, and set path" + " variable to your media file URL/path", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

  return;


  } else {
        /*
         * Alternatively,for streaming media you can use
         * mVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(URLstring));
         */
        mVideoView.setVideoPath(path);
        mVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(getActivity()));
        mVideoView.setVideoChroma(MediaPlayer.VIDEOCHROMA_RGB565);
        mVideoView.requestFocus();

        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                // optional need Vitamio 4.0
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mediaPlayer.setPlaybackSpeed(1.0f);

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: You need to state what the problem is. I'm not seeing a specific question here. What part are you having trouble with?

Comment: I need to retrieve the path from database instead of declared like private String path = "rtmp://live.dltv.cn:1935/live/live11";

Comment: In my case, once the IPTV source url changed, i need to modified the code.
Hence, i need to read the url from my database instead of declare in java coding

Comment: so basically, you're asking how to use a database. You'll have to learn the basics of databases and SQL first, then how to communicate with the database from your program. A simple SQLite database is explained in [this tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_java.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Try to save the path as a SharedPreference, make the user save the path in there and retrieve the preference.

Comment: Hi, I think I was misleading my problem, In my case, once the IPTV source url changed, i need to modified the code. Hence, i need to read the url from my database instead of declare in java coding

Comment: Well, from which database? You have to learn how to use a database then. A SharedPreference might be easier, I thought you needed this since something similar is addressed in your code.

Comment: from MySql database ... i have no idea how android connect to php.
Mostly code that i found from google are retrieve data and display in table or listview, but what i want is assign it as variable